# What is the characterstic function?

Tags: characteristic-functions

Good evening,

what is the characteristic function of a distribution with density function
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\lambda}e^{-\frac{|x|}{\lambda}},$$
while $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with parameter $\lambda > 0$?

Comment: Do you know what the definition of characteristic function is?

Comment: Here it is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Example Don't be surprised if you get a lot of down votes for your question

Comment: I'm just a Wikipedia-bot these days. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution#Relation_to_the_exponential_distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As yet I've got:

$$\frac{1}{2\lambda}\exp\left(-\frac{|x|}{\lambda}\right) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2\lambda}\exp\left(-\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)&, x\geq 0 \\ \frac{1}{2\lambda}\exp\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)&,x<0 \end{cases}$$

Now, I define my characteristic function

\begin{align*}
\varphi_X(t)&=\mathbb{E}(e^{itX}) \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{itx}\frac{1}{2\lambda}\exp\left(-\frac{|x|}{\lambda}\right) dx \\
&=\frac{1}{2\lambda}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{itx}\exp\left(-\frac{|x|}{\lambda}\right) dx \\
&=\frac{1}{2\lambda}\left(\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{itx}\exp\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right) + \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{itx}\exp\left(-\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)\right).
\end{align*}
I know that $e^{itx} = \cos(tx)+i\sin(tx)$ and I look the first integral:

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{itx}\exp\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right) &= \int_{-\infty}^0(\cos(tx)+i\sin(tx))\exp(\frac{x}{\lambda}dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^0 \cos(tx)\exp(\frac{x}{\lambda})dx + i\int_{-\infty}^0 \sin(tx)\exp(\frac{x}{\lambda})dx
\end{align*}
After the calculation I have:
$$\varphi_X(t) = \frac{(1-i)\lambda t}{\lambda^2t^2+1}$$
Is it right?